# Enforcing Paired Statements Using ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell

I really like c#'s `Using` statement as it allows you to pair `Open` statements with their corresponding `Close`/`Dispose` statements in an elegant way which matches C#'s syntax.
I realised that something similar can be achieved in PowerShell; e.g. `Push-Location` should be paired with a `Pop-Location`, and this can be enforced by creating a function which allows you to use a `USING`-like syntax.

e.g.

```
function PushDPopD {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [string]$Path
        , 
        [scriptblock]$Code
    )
    process {
        if (Push-Location $Path -PassThru) { #only proceed with this function's logic if our pushd were successful
            try {
                $Code.Invoke()
            } finally { #ensure that whatever happens in user code, we always popd after our pushd
                Pop-Location
            }
        }
    }
}
function ShowCurrentLocation {
    ("You are in: {0}" -f (Get-Location).Path)
}

Clear-Host
[string]$localVariable = "We keep variables even in scriptblock context"

write-host "`n`n==Healthy Demo==`n`n" -ForegroundColor cyan
ShowCurrentLocation 
PushDPopD 'c:\Users' {
    "hello"
    ShowCurrentLocation
    $localVariable  
    "bye"
}
ShowCurrentLocation 

write-host "`n`n==Exception Demo==`n`n" -ForegroundColor cyan
ShowCurrentLocation 
PushDPopD 'c:\ThisPathDoesNotExist' {
    "hello"
    ShowCurrentLocation 
    $localVariable 
    "bye"
}
ShowCurrentLocation
```

To me this seems like a logical approach / looks neater than manually checking that all pushes are correctly paired with pops.
The only potential issue is if someone includes a `popd` in the scriptblock itself; but that's no worse than the original scenario, so isn't a big drawback.
This also gives us the advantage that code won't blindly run on thinking it's in a different directory to the one specified if the `pushd` fails.

As a concept does this seem logical / have I missed anything.

NB: I'm aware it's not currently following `verb-noun` convention; that's because it's just proof of concept code, so I've not yet put any thought into suitable naming (suggestions welcome though).

Comment: One issue occurred; if the scriptblock throws an error (e.g. I add a new line with `1/0` somewhere in the `Code` parameter's value, the error will show as coming from the `$Code.Invoke()` line, rather than the actual line-in-error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest I feel this might be overcomplicating things.

I use `Push-Location`/`Pop-Location` in `try`/`finally` blocks when needed (like when loading the `SQLPS` module), but that's almost never.

For the most part I think one should avoid changing the current location and instead reference the desired path (either relative or absolute). So something like:

```
$p = $BasePath | Join-Path -ChildPath 'subfolder'
Get-ChildItem -Path $p
```

rather than:

```
$p = $BasePath | Join-Path -ChildPath 'subfolder'
Push-Location $p
try {
    Get-ChildItem
} finally {
    Pop-Location
}
```

As you've seen, there are also some issues with using scriptblocks in that way. You might have scope issues with variables, and call stack/execution context will be a bit different. This might get complicated further when you consider pipelines.

So in summary I'd rather avoid changing the working directory and then **not** obfuscate the process when I do so it's clear what's going on.